# How to send a function results from another command in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I am trying to write a bash script, called unpack,​​ which can unpack multiple packed files. It can even traverse folders recursively and unpack all archives in them - regardless of the specific algorithm that was used when packing them.

The exact synopsis is as follows:

```
unpack [-r] [-v] file [file...]
```

Given a list of filenames as input, this script queries each target file (parsing the output of the file​​ command) for the type of compression used on it. Then the script automatically invokes the appropriate decompression command, putting files in the same folder.

If files with the same name already exist, they are overwritten. 
now- my code is:

```
command=${1?Error: no command given}
arr="($@)"
for ((i=0; i<=3; i++))
do
    --here I want to send to $command $arr[i]
    echo "$i: ${arr[i]}"
done
```

I have few questions:

a. Is that the best way? I mean, the required syntax for call it is:  'unpack [-r] [-v] file [file...]',
maybe there is a way I could send to unpack the results of file command in the first place?

b. how can I combine 2 for loop options something like go over all the arguments start from the second one?
c. if this is the best way- how could I send arguments to command from script, and how can I turn the $command (string data type) to a command?

Currently my code is:

```
echo "${arr[i]}" | xargs $command
```

Now this code is printing for each argument it's type. But I'd like to decompress each one of them. How can I deal with xargs results?

Comment: `arr="($@)"` doesn't do what you think it does. `arr` is not an array, it's a normal variable. That `unpack [-r] [-v] file [file...]` is [this tool](https://linux.die.net/man/1/unzip)? If so, it can output the data with `-p` to stdout, then you can redirect it.

Comment: Can you clarify requirement - what type of 'packed files' need to be supported - are you talking about tgz, zip, bz2, ... ?

Comment: @dash-o Unpack should support 4 unpacking options - ​gunzip​​, ​bunzip2​​, ​unzip​​, ​uncompress​​. Adding more options should be VERY simple.

Comment: .bz2 .cmpr .gz .zip

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to use the output of a command as input to the next one:

- Pipe

Example : filter a text file and sort the results:

```
    grep "something" filename.txt | sort
```

Explanation : first the file gets filtered, and `grep` wants to show the results on screen. Those lines, however, get used as an input of the `sort` command, which sorts the results and shows those.

This way of working is mostly used in single-command commandline.

- Passing output of a command/function as input of for another command/function.

This can be done, using `$(...)` or backticks ````:

```
    chmod 777 $(pwd)
    chmod 777 `pwd`
```

This way of working is more used within a script.

Comment: if I want to do something with the results:
my code now is: I edited the question.